# Как создать приложение Android  в Eclipse?

Tags: android-sdk, android, eclipse

Подскажите, почему `Eclipse` отказывается создавать приложение `Android`, запускаю `Eclipse`, всплывает окно, типа надо проверить обновление, заканчивается проверка тем, что все уже было обновлено, обновлений не требуется. Нажимаю `New->Android Application`, заполняю имя, остальные поля автозаполняются, а кнопки `Next` и `Finish` заблокированы. Что делать?

Comment: может имя проекта задано плохое?

Comment: android  sdk и jdk точно установлен ?

Comment: "всплывает окно, типа надо проверить обновление" - скопируйте текст из окна в поисковик, наверняка проблема известна, как и известно ее решение. Меня этот метод борьбы с Eclipse(а глючит он довольно часто) еще ни разу не подвёл

Comment: Поставьте сборку от гугла?
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: Возможно на самом деле нужно обновить эклипс, window - update eclipse

Comment: Дайте скриншот заполненного окна нового проекта, в котором кнопки заблокированы и eclipce- window- preferences- android

Comment: используй IDEA от JetBrains, и будешь счастлив

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Соглашусь с комментарием Чада, ставьте это: [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

> The Android SDK provides you the API libraries and developer tools necessary to build, test, and debug apps for Android.

Comment: Присоединяясь к ТС, хочу дополнить вопрос. На Хабре в статье http://habrahabr.ru/post/109944/ автор отдельно ставит Eclipse и Android SDK — зачем, если в самой поставке Android SDK есть Eclipse?

Можно ли не качать отдельный пакет Eclipse, пользуясь имеющимся?

Comment: @Bars, можно и не скачивать отдельно. мне например удобно использовать Eclipse Indigo,а там кажется идет Eclipse Juno

Comment: @Bars, статья на хабре - 2010 года, ее автор тогда не в курсе был видимо.